# Leaflet - get a map that covers the full screen

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

In leaflet and mapbox I would like to get rid of the two gray bars above and under the map as seen on the picture below. My #map DOM element takes the full screen and the gray bars disappear when I zoom in (e.g., zoomLevel = 3). So the gray bars seem to be caused by the fact that a zoomLevel has a given height (in px) of the tiles which is smaller than my screen.

I want to keep the tiles of the same zoom level but make sure the height of the tiles cover at least the full screen.

[image]

Here is my map setup code:

```
                vm.map = L.map('map', {
                    center: [35, 15],
                    zoom: 2,
                    maxZoom: 21,
                    scrollWheelZoom: true,
                    maxBounds: [
                    [89.9, 160.9],
                    [-89.9, -160.9]
                    ],
                    zoomControl: false,
                    noWrap: true,
                    zoomAnimation: true,
                    markerZoomAnimation: true,
                });
```

I am using angular and my screen dimensions are 1920 x 1080

Comment: I managed to get rid of the bars by adding the followin css property to my #map element: `transform: scale(1.1)`. However, this creates a mess in the rest of my code so I am looking for something else.

Comment: You could try to make leaflet repeat the map vertically. However this is not supported by the official repo at the moment ( https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/904) so you may want to open a PR for that. It should not be too hard to do since it is already implemented for the x-axis.

Comment: Thank you @Buddyshot. You seem to follow me well and answer all my questions ! A good illustration of the awesomeness of open source. I'll first check if I can fix my issue with the existing leaflet package and otherwise implement your solution.

Comment: Just found this option: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-continuousworld Can you give it a try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to calculate the minimum zoom level at which the map only shows the area between 85°N and 85°S.

The [`getBoundsZoom()` method of `L.Map`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-getboundszoom) helps with this, e.g.:

```
var bounds = L.latLngBounds([[85, 180],[-85, -180]]);
var wantedZoom = map.getBoundsZoom(bounds, true);
var center = bounds.getCenter();
map.setView(center, wantedZoom);
```

Note that this is a generic solution, and works for any size of the map container.

You could also set the `minZoom` of the map to that value, and experiment with fractional zoom (see the `zoomSnap` option). If you want the user to be unable to drag outside the painted area, use the map's `maxBounds` option with something like `[[85, Infinity],[-85, -Infinity]]`.

(And if you are wondering why 85°N and 85°S, do read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator )

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be an elegant solution. However, in my specific case it is important to keep the tiles of zoom level = 2, otherwise my map is getting too ugly. In fact, I would need a zoom level of 2.1 or so that just scales up a little bit the tiles of zoom level 2. Or alternatively, a feature to scale up/down tile size at a given zoom level.

Comment: As I said already, experiment with `zoomSnap`. Try setting `zoomSnap` to `0.1` and `minZoom` to `2.1`. :-)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!